# Cannot import name include

Tags: python, django

I am following the tutorial in django and obtaining the following error.

Found few solutions but it didn't resolve my error. The tutorial link is [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/).

The error which I obtained is attached below. Please help me with this before duplicating the question. I am learning python and django services so it would help ma a lot.

```
ImportError at /polls/

cannot import name include

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

cannot import name include

Exception Location:     /home/next/Desktop/MBS/python_files/progs/django_examples/mysite/../mysite/urls.py in <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/next/Desktop/MBS/python_files/progs/django_examples/mysite',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQRCode-1.2-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-22.0.0-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']

Server time:    Mon, 6 Jun 2016 00:03:30 -0500
```

Edit 1: I will attach the urls.py of both so it would help to identify

in polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

and mysite/urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import include, url
 from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Edit 2:The trace log is attached below

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/polls/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
 99.                             request.path_info)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
 269.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
 298.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
 293.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
 35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/next/Desktop/MBS/python_files/progs/django_examples/mysite/../mysite/urls.py" in <module>
 1. from django.conf.urls import include, url

Exception Type: ImportError at /polls/
Exception Value: cannot import name include
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: do you mean that the error log which i get during the running process?

Comment: Yes, the full set of error messages giving reference to various parts of the code base

Comment: check the edited question with stacktrace above @e4c5

Comment: do ./manage.py shell and then type from django.conf.urls import include, url to see what happens.

Comment: Can you say briefly please. can't understand what are you trying to say. am new to this software django

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution for the above mentioned question. The version of the django is the main cause. Updating the django version cleared the error which was raised previously.

the version before updating was 1.3 and now the version is 1.10

To update the django version,

```
$ sudo pip install -U Django
```

Comment: I got `Unsupported Python version` error. what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

well you have to include `include` in `polls` `urls`

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Comment: tried it out now. But it didnot work @Raja Simon

Comment: check my edited question with urls files

Comment: @anandmbs i see no error in there... tell why you are `include` in polls ?

Comment: I cant get you raja what is the error. and what are you trying to say

Comment: can you remove the include in polls and try ?

Comment: That was my initial code.. I added after you said to make changes